# Exact structures on representations of a finite group

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, modular-representation-theory, exact-categories

For simplicity assume $G$ is a (finite) $p$-group, and $k$ is field of characteristic $p$, so that there exists a unique simple $kG$-module the trivial module $k$. I am looking for a class of short exact sequences on the category of finite $kG$-modules such that

1. The category is a Quillen exact category with this class taken as admissible conflations,
2. The relative Grothendieck group $K_0$ is **not** $\mathbb{Z}$, generated by $k$,
3. All cocommutative Hopf algebras $\Delta : kG \to kG \otimes kG$ produce the same commutative ring structure on $K_0$. In particular $K_0$ is a well defined ring, meaning the subgroup generated by Euler relations is an ideal of the big ring of representations, with product given by the tensor defined from $\Delta$.

I have this question now because I had found a promising class based on cohomological support that turned out to fail condition 2. My idea was to keep the support theory intact by only admitting $V' \hookrightarrow V \twoheadrightarrow V''$ when $\operatorname{supp}(V) = \operatorname{supp}(V')\cup \operatorname{supp}(V'').$ This class satisfies condition 1. (exercise!), but alas, the group $K_0$ is `trivial' as $\mathbb{Z}$. We can see this by filtering any module to have trivial subquotients, and appending a trivial module to all the relevant short exact sequences to make them admissible (i.e. the left and middle terms can be made to be supported everywhere by adding a trivial module). Then subtract off trivial modules to see we've identified $[V] = d[k]$ for each module $V$ of dimension $d$ over $k$. Now condition 3 is an immediate consequence, but for support-theory reasons it looked promising even before knowing $K_0$ was trivial: the class of exact sequences is itself tensor-ideal by the property $\operatorname{supp}(V\otimes W) = \operatorname{supp}(V)\cap \operatorname{supp}(W)$. This is a stronger condition than the subgroup generated by Euler relations being ideal in some inductive manner.

For $G = \mathbb{Z} / p$, the class of split exact sequences satisfies all these conditions: 1. and 2. are automatic and, less trivially, all cocommutative Hopf algebras on $kG \cong k[t]/t^p$ produce the same separated-by-two rules for tensoring a pair of indecomposable modules.

For $G$ the Klein 4-group, the only noncyclic computable example, we necessarily need more than the split exact sequences for condition 3. We ought to include some in the form $V \hookrightarrow W \twoheadrightarrow V$ where $V, W$ are indecomposable, nonprojective, and $V$ is of dimension $2$, as for some tensor products we get $V^2 = W$ and for others we get $V^2 = 2V$ (it is more precise to say we must somehow induce the relation $W = 2V$, but in any case this is not induced from the split exact sequences alone).

Is there any noncyclic $G$ for which such a class of exact sequences is known? Perhaps fix $G = $ the Klein 4 group and $k = $ an algebraically closed field of characteristic 2. Then it is possible to know all pairs of finite modules $W, W'$ such that $V \otimes V' = W$ in one Hopf algebra and $W'$ in another for some pair $V, V'$, and we may work backwards to induce the relations $W = W'$ from an exact structure. Of course it would be more enlightening to have a class of exact sequences for a generic group, but I am out of ideas.